# If the decision problem can be solved in poly time, show the optimization problem also can

Tags: np-complete, optimization, decision-problem, np

Here is a problem I am trying to solve:

> The bin packing decision problem is defined as follows: given an unlimited number of
>   bins, each of capacity equal to $1$, and $n$ objects with sizes $s_1$, $s_2$, $\dots$, $s_n$ ($0 < s_i ≤ 1$), do the objects fit in $k$ bins (where $k$ is a given
>   integer)? The bin packing optimization problem is to find the smallest
>   number of bins into which the objects can be packed. Show that if the
>   decision problem can be solved in polynomial time, then the
>   optimization problem can also be solved in polynomial time.

I know what it is asking but I don't know what the "optimization" problem for this is. Is it the grouping of all the objects into different bins (for instance, $s_1$, $s_3$, and $s_6$ are in bin #$1$, $s_2$, $s_4$, $s_5$ are in bin #$2$, etc.)? Or is it simply the number of bins you need to store them? I feel like the number of bins is the decision problem...

Comment: (I would've defined the optimization problem as "find _a packing of the objects into_ the smallest $\hspace{.57 in}$ number of bins into which the objects can be packed".) $\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the decision problem, $k$ is given, so the answer is yes, or no (a **decision**). In the optimization problem $k$ is unknown, and we have to find out how small can it be (the **optimal** solution). The bigger question asks if there is a logical connection between possible solutions to these two problems, such that the complexity of the respective algorithms is corelated.

Comment: so can we just increment k from 0 to infinity and find when the decision problem returns true? is that poly? we have no idea when its gonna terminate

Comment: Well, that's another question... ;-) And you seem to be very close to the answer.

Comment: See, the problem you were given allows you to *assume* that the decision problem can be solved in polynomial time. That makes it quite easy.

Comment: okay, so we just keep incrementing the k until it returns yes, then we know it can fit in k bins and the running time is O(k n^i) for some integer i (since its polynomial time to decide) and the value k is how many times we ran this?

Comment: but how do i determine the actual optimal solution for fitting the items? Which items go in which bin?

Comment: It's $O(f(n)n^i)$ (and $f(n)$ is the number of attempts - a function of $n$, investigate what could this be). The answer to your last question is: write a version of the program you just specified, and see what it gives you (of course, you will have to find an algorithm that solves the decision problem - in polynomial time, should it exist). Should be fun!

Comment: @user2237160. "but how do I determine the actual optimal solution...Which items go in which bin?" You can't determine that using this construction.  By the way, a binary search for $k$ is what you want to use, but in any case that will just answer the question "What is the least value of $k$ for which there is a solution?"

Comment: @user2237160 Also, check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem.